# how to create excel sheet with specific template?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I cant find out how to create excel sheet using office interop assembly with specific template although it doesn't seem hard.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has examples in this site http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet. You need references of `Microsoft.Office.Interop` of Office in your project.

Create from template (see more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx)

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Create new Application.
    Dim excel As Application = New Application

    Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add("c:\templateFileName")

    ' Close.
    w.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Read from file:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Create new Application.
    Dim excel As Application = New Application

    ' Open Excel spreadsheet.
    Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xls")

    ' Loop over all sheets.
    For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count

        ' Get sheet.
        Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(i)

        ' Get range.
        Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange

        ' Load all cells into 2d array.
        Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

        ' Scan the cells.
        If array IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", array.Length)

        ' Get bounds of the array.
        Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1)

        Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0: {0}", bound0)
        Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1: {0}", bound1)

        ' Loop over all elements.
        For j As Integer = 1 To bound0
            For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
            Dim s1 As String = array(j, x)
            Console.Write(s1)
            Console.Write(" "c)
            Next
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
        End If
    Next

    ' Close.
    w.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, this code gets data from excel sheet and puts them into an array and outputs the array contents. How would this code create a worksheet of specific template?